# How to call a closure with a delay in Rust? Is tokio::timer::Delay a proper tool for making asynchronous callbacks?

Tags: rust

How to call a closure with a delay in Rust? Is `tokio::timer::Delay` a proper tool for making asynchronous callbacks?

My code:

```rust
pub struct Object1 {
    k1: i32,
}

//

impl Object1 {
    pub fn new() -> Object1 {
        Object1 { k1: 13 }
    }
}

//

fn main() {
    let object1: Box<Object1> = Box::new(Object1::new());

    callback_call_1(Box::new(|| {
        println!("{:?}", object1.k1);
    }));
}

//

fn callback_call_1<F>(mut callback1: F)
where
    F: FnMut(),
{
    println!("inside callback_call_1");
    callback1();
    /* how to call callback1 with delay 1 second, not blocking the thread?
    is it possible to call the callback1 in the same thread?
    is it possible to reach similar behavior setTimeout from JavaScript has?
    */
}
```

Here is [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=862e7baafc70026a684ffd3e3807460c).

Comment: Have you read [Asynchronous Programming in Rust](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it with latest Tokio:

```rust
tokio::time::sleep(duration).await;
callback1().await;
```

To call it repeatedly on an interval, use a loop:

```rust
let mut interval = tokio::time::interval(duration);
loop {
    interval.tick().await;
    callback1().await;
}
```

Comment: Any alternative?